# Confirming that jar files are being loaded

Tags: coldfusion

How can I confirm that my JAR files have been loaded in Coldfusion? I'm on CF10.

I'm currently getting this error:

```
Could not find the ColdFusion component or interface org.apache.batik.transcoder.image.PNGTranscoder.
```

My site structure goes as follow:

```
/root
/root/application.cfc
/root/jar/batik-1.7/
```

In my application.cfc, I have the following code:

```
<cfset This.javaSettings = {loadPaths: ["jar/"],loadColdFusionClassPath: true,reloadOnChange: true,watchInterval: 2}>
```

Here is my code in terms of calling everything:

```
<cffunction name="getPng" access="public" output="true">        
    <cfsavecontent variable="out">
    <!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
    <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
         width="612px" height="792px" viewBox="0 0 612 792" enable-background="new 0 0 612 792" xml:space="preserve">
    <path fill="##006838" stroke="##414042" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M416.413,388.223c0,6.627-5.373,12-12,12H140.317
        c-6.627,0-12-5.373-12-12V272.54c0-6.627,5.373-12,12-12h264.096c6.627,0,12,5.373,12,12V388.223z"/>
    <text id="HomeScore" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 358.5391 361.333)" fill="##F1F2F2" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="24">3</text>
    <text id="Home" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 155.3018 361.333)" fill="##F1F2F2" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="24">TEAM B</text>
    <text id="VisitorScore" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 358.5391 301.8096)" fill="##F1F2F2" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="24">2</text>
    <text id="Visitor" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 155.3018 301.8096)" fill="##F1F2F2" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="24">TEAM A</text>
    </svg>
    </cfsavecontent>

    <cfreturn out>
</cffunction>

<cffunction name="renderPng" access="public" output="false">
    <cfscript>

        /*http://cfsearching.blogspot.ca/2008/02/cool-text-effects-with-svg-and-batik.html*/
        pngPath = "test.png";
        pngFile = expandPath(pngPath);

        transcoder = createObject("java", "org.apache.batik.transcoder.image.PNGTranscoder").init();
        inputStream = createObject("java", "java.io.StringBufferInputStream").init(getPng());
        input = createObject("java", "org.apache.batik.transcoder.TranscoderInput").init(inputStream);
        outputStream = createObject("java", "java.io.FileOutputStream").init(ExpandPath(pngFile));
        output = createObject("java", "org.apache.batik.transcoder.TranscoderOutput").init(outputStream);
        transcoder.transcode(input, output);
        outputStream.close();

        return pngFile;
    </cfscript>

</cffunction>

<cfscript>
    // CREATE OBJECT 
    obj = createObject("component", "#request.cfcPath#.utils");
    // CALL THE FUNCTION
    png = obj.renderPng();
</cfscript>
```

**Update #1**

I was checking in the administor and found `Settings Summary`, which listed `CF Server Java Class Path`. I added the location of my jar files and rebooted the server. Even though the path is present in the class path in the Administrator, I still get that same error.

**Update 2**

Added the missing attribute "type" and getting the following error:

`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/batik/dom/util/DocumentFactory`

`Line 554: transcoder = createObject("java", "org.apache.batik.transcoder.image.PNGTranscoder").init();`

Full stack trace

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.batik.dom.util.DocumentFactory at coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapClassLoader.loadClass(BootstrapClassLoader.java:235) at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356) at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method) at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2317) at java.lang.Class.privateGetPublicFields(Class.java:2350) at java.lang.Class.getFields(Class.java:1378) at coldfusion.runtime.java.ObjectHandler.Initialize(ObjectHandler.java:35) at coldfusion.runtime.java.ObjectHandler.(ObjectHandler.java:30) at coldfusion.runtime.java.ReflectionCache.get(ReflectionCache.java:38) at coldfusion.runtime.java.JavaProxy.(JavaProxy.java:35) at coldfusion.runtime.java.JavaProxyFactory.getProxy(JavaProxyFactory.java:117) at coldfusion.runtime.ProxyFactory.getProxy(ProxyFactory.java:65) at coldfusion.runtime.CFPage.createObjectProxy(CFPage.java:5747) at coldfusion.runtime.CFPage.CreateObject(CFPage.java:5710) at coldfusion.runtime.CFPage.CreateObject(CFPage.java:5644) at coldfusion.runtime.CFPage.CreateObject(CFPage.java:5619) at coldfusion.runtime.CFPage.CreateObject(CFPage.java:5566) at cfutils2ecfc521921384$funcRENDERPNG.runFunction(C:\websites\mgs_bootstrap\basic\cfc\utils.cfc:554) at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:472) at coldfusion.filter.SilentFilter.invoke(SilentFilter.java:47) at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ArgumentCollectionFilter.invoke(UDFMethod.java:368) at coldfusion.filter.FunctionAccessFilter.invoke(FunctionAccessFilter.java:55) at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.runFilterChain(UDFMethod.java:321) at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:220) at coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxy.invoke(TemplateProxy.java:655) at coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxy.invoke(TemplateProxy.java:444) at coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxy.invoke(TemplateProxy.java:414) at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._invoke(CfJspPage.java:2432) at cfsvgtest2ecfm1573707502.runPage(C:\websites\mgs_bootstrap\svgtest.cfm:5) at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage.invoke(CfJspPage.java:244) at coldfusion.tagext.lang.IncludeTag.doStartTag(IncludeTag.java:444) at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._emptyTcfTag(CfJspPage.java:2799) at cfapplication2ecfc733577694$funcONREQUEST.runFunction(C:\websites\mgs_bootstrap\application.cfc:87) at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:472) at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ArgumentCollectionFilter.invoke(UDFMethod.java:368) at coldfusion.filter.FunctionAccessFilter.invoke(FunctionAccessFilter.java:55) at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.runFilterChain(UDFMethod.java:321) at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:220) at coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxy.invoke(TemplateProxy.java:655) at coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxy.invoke(TemplateProxy.java:444) at coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxy.invoke(TemplateProxy.java:414) at coldfusion.runtime.AppEventInvoker.invoke(AppEventInvoker.java:108) at coldfusion.runtime.AppEventInvoker.onRequest(AppEventInvoker.java:300) at coldfusion.filter.ApplicationFilter.invoke(ApplicationFilter.java:418) at coldfusion.filter.RequestMonitorFilter.invoke(RequestMonitorFilter.java:48) at coldfusion.filter.MonitoringFilter.invoke(MonitoringFilter.java:40) at coldfusion.filter.PathFilter.invoke(PathFilter.java:112) at coldfusion.filter.LicenseFilter.invoke(LicenseFilter.java:30) at coldfusion.filter.ExceptionFilter.invoke(ExceptionFilter.java:94) at coldfusion.filter.BrowserDebugFilter.invoke(BrowserDebugFilter.java:79) at coldfusion.filter.ClientScopePersistenceFilter.invoke(ClientScopePersistenceFilter.java:28) at coldfusion.filter.BrowserFilter.invoke(BrowserFilter.java:38) at coldfusion.filter.NoCacheFilter.invoke(NoCacheFilter.java:46) at coldfusion.filter.GlobalsFilter.invoke(GlobalsFilter.java:38) at coldfusion.filter.DatasourceFilter.invoke(DatasourceFilter.java:22) at coldfusion.filter.CachingFilter.invoke(CachingFilter.java:62) at coldfusion.CfmServlet.service(CfmServlet.java:204) at coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapServlet.service(BootstrapServlet.java:89) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210) at coldfusion.monitor.event.MonitoringServletFilter.doFilter(MonitoringServletFilter.java:42) at coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapFilter.doFilter(BootstrapFilter.java:46) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169) at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168) at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98) at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:928) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118) at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:414) at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.process(AjpProcessor.java:203) at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:539) at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:298) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

**Update 3**

I have this in my application.cfc

`<cfset This.javaSettings = {loadPaths: ["jar/"],loadColdFusionClassPath: false,reloadOnChange: true,watchInterval: 2}>`

I called `onApplicationStart()` and still getting that same error.

At this point, I have removed my entry in the ColdFusion Class Path and it's now back to the default value which is empty.

I want it to work loading the jar files using the `javaSettings` variable as I'm on shared hosting.

Comment: (Edit) Hmm... just noticed you forgot to include the object "type" in your createObject call. The default is "component". You need to tell CF you want to create an instance of a java class: ie `createObject("java", "path.to.SomeClassName")`. That is what the error is complaining about.

Comment: @Leigh added the type attribute, see update #2 for results.

Comment: Basically that means there is a problem loading the newer version of the jar(s), since there is already another version in the class path. Try setting `loadColdFusionClassPath` to false. Be sure to restart the app so the new settings are applied.

Comment: @leigh see update 3... still not working, same error... confirmed that the application restarted as I set an application variable and it got output in the debugger.

Comment: Can you include the full stack trace for the error in "Update 2"? We need to see more of the exception, ie "Caused by:" etcetera. (Edit) I saw a thread which suggested a missing jar, but ... it all depends on the cause reported in the trace.

Comment: @leigh Done. Stack trace added to update #2.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58807/discussion-between-leigh-and-tekiusfanatikus).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update:**

(Summary from chat) Batik 1.7 includes newer versions of two xml parsing libraries that are already bundled with CF 10. Loading both versions will cause a ClassCastException

> org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl cannot be cast to
>   javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory

To avoid that error, remove these two xml jars from the `batik-1.7/lib` directory so they are not loaded:

```
  /batik-1.7/lib/xerces_2_5_0.jar
  /batik-1.7/lib/xml-apis.jar
```

Also, `loadPaths` is not recursive. So if there are any jars contained in subfolders, you must include the path of those subfolders as well. ie

```
   This.javaSettings = {loadPaths: ["/jar/batik-1.7","/jar/batik-1.7/lib"]};
```

If you make changes to the `this.javaSettings`, be sure to restart the application to ensure the changes are applied.

---

> Could not find the ColdFusion **component** or interface

When you use `createObject`, you need to include the object "type". Otherwise, it uses the default type "component". Meaning CF is searching for a *component/cfc* with the path you supplied ie "org.apache.batik.transcoder.image.PNGTranscoder". Since your application probably does not contain a cfc with that path, that is why you are getting the error message above.

Add type `"java"` to all of your `createObject` calls and it should work:

```
createObject("java", "org.apache.batik.transcoder.image.PNGTranscoder").init();
```

Comment: Thanks for spotting my inconsistencies... did that, getting a new error. See update #2.

Comment: FWIW, I uploaded my code on my shared hosting and it worked out of the box, no need to move files or have the service rebooted (which would have never happened anyways). I'll be searching to explain why this.javaSettings doesn't work in my dev environment.... thanks again for the help

Comment: To be honest, that is more consistent with what I experienced when I tried it locally. All I did was extract the jars, add the subdirectory `lib/` to the paths, then changed the Application.cfc name to ensure I was starting with a clean slate scratch. I know you mentioned you restarted the application, but .. maybe something in your earlier tests was still mucking things? At least from the perspective of `this.javaSettings` anyway.

Comment: Yep, works nicely for a quick dev test when you do not care about any app/sessions being dropped. Not so much for production ;-)

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar issue where the order of the classpath caused the issue in CF2021. I included a jar file first, but that should have been done later after all the main libraries were loaded.  So, in my experience, realized that when adding new jars to the classpath, always add at the end.